# how to create image tracker with ar.js

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, ar.js

I hope you are all doing well.
I am new to the world of javascript and web design. I am planning to create an augmented reality for my site. At first, I used unity and wanted to get webgl output. But due to the use of vofuria engine, I understood that webgl will not be usable. That's why I went to Ar.js. But unfortunately, no matter how hard I try and follow different templates, I can't find a way. I have put the code I use here and also put all the required data publicly in AWS storage space. This information and data have been uploaded from this [github](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/tree/master) itself. Thank you very much for your help and guidance

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1.3.0/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<!-- rawgithack development URL -->
<!--<script src='https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js'></script>-->
<script src='https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ar.js/trex-sample/aframe-ar-nft.js'></script>


<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
   <!-- minimal loader shown until image descriptors are loaded -->
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
    <a-scene
        vr-mode-ui='enabled: false;'
        renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true; precision: medium;"
        embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

        <!-- use rawgithack to retrieve the correct url for nft marker (see 'pinball' below) -->
        <a-nft
            type='nft' url='https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ar.js/trex-sample/trex/trex-image/trex' 
            smooth='true' smoothCount='10' smoothTolerance='0.01' smoothThreshold='5'>
            <a-entity
                gltf-model='https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ar.js/trex-sample/trex/scene.gltf'
                scale="5 5 5"
                position="150 300 -100"
                >
            </a-entity>
        </a-nft>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```